# Excel COUNTIFS with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to use a `COUNTIF` formula with two criteria.
This is the formula I have now.
It's obviously wrong, but I think it shows what I want.

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$1008; P36 & $B$2:$B$1008; P21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what COUNTIFS(with and S) is for:

```
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$1008; P36; $B$2:$B$1008; P21)
```

Comment: Thanks. And how does that work with SUMIFS?

I have this now:

   `=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$1008; P36; $B$2:$B$1008; P21; $I$2:$I$1008)`

Comment: That is a different question than this one, But SUMIFS, order is different, you put the column to sum first not last: `=SUMIFS($I$2:$I$1008;$D$2:$D$1008; P36; $B$2:$B$1008; P21) `  If this worked for your original question, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.